How to install fix vulnerability
i have ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and our scanner find that vulnerability but i really dont know how to applay that on my machine
CVE
(libbpf
Launchpad, Ubuntu, Debian)
I made:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot

Can someone write me steps by steps what command i should use ? Please help me

Your scanner likely doesn't know anything about Ubuntu security patching process. It sees version X.Y == vulnerable, even though the actual package is X.Y-ubuntuZ with patches applied. Check if the package you have installed is newer than the one listed in the CVE tracker, that's all.

See the answer in that post that tells you how to check package changelogs, if you want more confirmation.

According to the link you provided the CVE has been fixed in 22.04.01 (jammy
Released (0.5.0-1ubuntu22.04.1))
So an upgrade, as you already did, should normally do it. Maybe sudo apt full-upgrade is needed, if packages has to be (un)installed too.

If there is any possibility to check that fix is installed ? maybe thats is a false possitive ?

Right, away it goes.
